# Como provocar um erro XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Eu gostaria de entender em que casos o `readyState` vai ser igual a 4 e o `status` vai ser diferente de 200 e a diferença disso para o evento `onerror`:

```
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.error(xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
}
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.error(xhr.statusText);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `.onerror` só será invocado caso haja erro a nível de rede, do contrário, sempre vai entrar no `.onload` e ignorar o `onerror`.

**Exemplo:**

Suponhamos que estou no site `http://meusite.com` e possuo um arquivo `index.html` no diretório raiz.

Se eu tentar chamar `xhr.open("GET","index.html",true);`:

- Irá entrar no `onload` **sem erro**, com `xhr.status == 200`, porque
  achou o arquivo normalmente.

Se eu tentar chamar `xhr.open("GET","indexxxxx.html",true);`:

- Irá entrar no `onload` "**com erro**" (na verdade não é um erro, mas apenas um retorno de que o arquivo não foi encontrado), com `xhr.status == 404`, porque
  não achou o arquivo.

Se eu tentar chamar `xhr.open("GET","http://google.com",true);`:

- Irá entrar no `onerror`, pois não é permitido chamar domínio
  diferente do atual e a requisição sequer foi enviada.

O `readyState` são fases da comunicação com o servidor (de 0 a 4), enquanto o `status` é interpretado pelo navegador (200, 404 etc...)

Comment: era exatamente isso que eu queria saber, perfeito.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a [página da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)*:

> Uma requisição XHR existe um dos seguintes estados:
>
> - 0 - UNSENT - Um cliente foi criado. Mas o método `open()`  não foi chamado ainda.
> - 1 - OPENED - O método `open()` foi chamado.
> - 2 - HEADERS_RECEIVED - O método `send()` foi chamado e os cabeçalhos e status estão disponíveis.
> - 3 - LOADING - Baixando e `responseText` contém os dados parciais.
> - 4 - DONE - Operação concluída.

Ou seja, quando o valor é 0, a requisição do `XMLHttpRequest` (AJAX) ainda não começou e quando for 4 ela já acabou. Os demais estados representam passos intermediários. Como o seu código só tem interesse em saber o resultado quando este estiver pronto, você tem o `if (xhr.readyState === 4)`.

Já o status é o [status HTTP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP). Os mais comuns são 200 (ok), 404 (página não encontrada), 403 (acesso negado), 500 (erro interno no servidor), entre outros. No seu caso, o 200 indica que deu certo e qualquer outra coisa seria um erro.

---

<sup><sub>* - Adaptado por mim para se adequar ao formato do SOpt.</sub></sup>