# Quais os valores possíveis no document.readyState?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, eventos, internet-explorer

Notei na documentação do [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState), tanto quando na documentação da [*W3*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-document-readystate) (não confundir com *w3schools*)

- **loading** documento carregando ainda
- **interactive** o documento já concluiu o carregamento e o "documento" já foi processado, mas imagens, estilos e frames ainda estão carregando
- **complete** o documento e recursos já foram carregados, este estado indica o mesmo que o evento (on)`load`

No entanto ao acessar o site da w3.org notei esta mensagem:

> This definition is non-normative. Implementation requirements are given below this definition.

E no site da [*MSDN*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752602(v=vs.85).aspx) notei que "API" mostra mais dois valores "possíveis":

- **uninitialized** O objeto não foi iniciado com os dados
- **loaded** Objeto terminou de carregar os dados

Eu não entendi bem a mensagem do `loaded`, por estar em inglês talvez, mas se entendi bem é que a estrutura "HTML" foi baixada, mas não renderizada, seria isto mesmo?

Outra duvida, ou melhor a duvida principal, `uninitialized` e `loaded` estão disponíveis no `Node.onreadystatechange` ou esses valores estão apenas disponíveis na API para desenvolver algo como um "webView" (ou até um browser próprio) usando a [*interface `IHTMLDocument2`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Adicional: Se por acaso estes valores forem disponiveis no IE além da API, eles também estarão disponíveis possivelmente disponíveis em outros navegadores?

Comment: Relacionada (talvez duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232001/132

Comment: Não, esse do meu comentário aí em cima é no caso do AJAX, e não no carregamento da página.

Comment: Isso mesmo @VictorStafusa, a interface de API de ambas é bastante semelhante, e usam até nomes de propriedades parecidos, mas o comportamento realmente não é exatamente igual.

Comment: São estes os states [antigos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268229(v=vs.85).aspx) e este os [novos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState). No mesmo link com os novos, há uma tabela com `Browser compatibility`. Porém, já encontrei várias dificuldades em utilizar somente o evento `ReadyState` para verificar se uma página foi aberta completamente, não funciona todas as vezes. Sempre precisei adicionar algum tempo de carregamento junto com `ReadyState`

Answer (score 1):

**Document.readyState:**

O `Document.readyState` tem por objetivo identificar o status de carregamento de um documento. Serve para interagir com a página em determinados estados de carregamento. Ele é usado baseado em eventos de referência notáveis ​​por ferramentas de desempenho e APIs. Essa métrica é relatada pelos navegadores.

`Document.readyState` possui três estados possíveis de resposta (loaded, interactive, complete):

**loaded:**

Informa se um documento está sendo carregado (loaded).

**loading:**

Estados em tempo de execução do readyState:

Ou seja, quando o `document.readyState` tem um status de "loading", significa que o documento (por exemplo um arquivo html do tipo index.html) está sendo analisado e tratado para fornecer um estado.

Outros sub-recursos da página ainda não são um fator, porque o documento inicial está apenas começando a analisar, portanto, o navegador não sabe se eles existem.

O html em si está atualmente baixado (o navegador possui o html), mas está sendo processado...

O carimbo de data / hora da API de sincronização de navegação "domLoading" é acionado imediatamente antes do documento ter um status de carregamento.

**interactive:**

Quando `document.readyState` tem um status "interactive", significa que o documento agora está analisado e carregado, mas sub-recursos como CSS e imagens ainda estão sendo carregados ou analisados. Quando `document.readyState` relata que é interativo, também significa que o evento `DOMContentLoaded` foi acionado.

**Interagindo com o readyState:**

Para cada alteração ocorrida em document.readyState (por exemplo, se o readyState mudar de "loading" para "interativo"), um evento **readystatechange** é acionado no objeto de documento. Usando o evento **readystatechange**, podemos interagir com essas "alterações".

**Exemplo:**

```
// alternativa para carregar o evento
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (document.readyState == "complete") {
       initApplication();
    }
}
```

**complete:**

Quando `document.readyState` tem um status "complete", significa que o documento agora é analisado e carregado e todos os sub-recursos de documentos conhecidos, como CSS e imagens, foram analisados ​​e carregados. Quando document.readyState relata que está completo, isso também significa que o evento de carregamento foi acionado.

**Em termos humanos:**

`Document.readyState` nos diz em que estágio está o carregamento da página. É a versão do navegador de "Are we there yet?" (Já chegamos?).

Essas informações podem ser usadas para interagir com a página enquanto ela está em diferentes estágios de carregamento de uma página.

> **Resumidamente**: de maneira geral, você só irá usar o `readyState` como uma condicional de estado, para interagir com seu objeto que está sendo renderizado...

Uma forma de capturar todos os eventos possíveis de um determinado evento com o `document.readyState`, no caso estou capturando eventos de uma requisição GET por ajax:

```
function handler() {
  console.log(this.readyState)
  //0 (não inicializado => uninitialized | esse é antes de qualquer estado, então ele não será impresso aqui dentro, pois ele não passa pelo onreadystatechange) 
  //1 (a carregar => loading) 
  //2 (carregado => loaded) 
  //3 (interactivo => interactive) 
  //4 (completo => complete)
}

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = handler;
client.open("GET", "https://www.google.com");
client.send();
```

**Curiosidade:** Se por exemplo, executar o código acima somente no seu console do navegador, provavelmente o `1` e o `4` somente serão definidos, porque `2` e `3` não são enxergados apenas pelo console.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas você respondeu todo o comportamento, que é algo que não foi o perguntado, porque sinceramente, tudo isso ai eu já sei, a pergunta é sobre quais os valores padrões e `uninitialized ` e se muda algo sobre o IHTMLDocument2 e porque.

Comment: [Veja se isso te ajuda](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa752602(v%3Dvs.85)). e [mais isso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event)

Comment: Ivan, tudo isto eu já li, a questão é sobre interfaces, variações e padrões disto. Eu vou resguardar um tempo para elaborar bem uma resposta, as APIs MS não são lá grandiosamente documentadas, mas hoje esta bem melhor.

Comment: Por que cada API tem um comportamento diferente mesmo, dependendo da linguagem que é utilizada, mas em tese, todas elas vão se basear dentro destes 3 estados. Algumas APIs não sabem alavancar, ou mesmo não necessitam de todos os 3 estados... é por isso que não é uma normatividade.

Comment: Olha o exemplo do `react-native`, que já trabalha com mudanças de estado, `getState`, `setState`, etc, ou uso de hooks... são apis que não necessitam de alguns destes estados.

Comment: react-native usa mudanças de estado proprias escritas para o proprio uso da lib, não tem haver com estado do DOM e nem com a necessidade da pergunta descrita aqui. Obrigado pelo esforço, mas o problema é outro.

Answer (score -6):

Os valores possíveis são:

- uninitialized
- loading
- loaded
- interactive
- complete

[Referência w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp)

Comment: Caro Daniel, não me leve a mal, mas não é bem isso que perguntei, leia a pergunta com calma e me desculpe, eu citei MDN e W3.org, w3schools não é uma boa referencia, as que citei são bem mais completas e exatas. Recomendo que revise a sua resposta. Até breve.